# syntax for conditional operator with {{ }} in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, conditional-operator

I am trying to implement a conditional operator on a value returned from controller to create some custom view.

**front.blade**

```
@if({{count($users)}} <= 5) <!-- if total number of rows in users table is less than or equal to 5 -->
          <h3> total number of rows less than or equal to 5 </h3> 
@endif
```

**controller**

```
$users = User::all();
return view('front', [ 'users'=>$users]);
```

and the error is

**syntax error, unexpected '<'(View: \resources\views\front.blade.php)**

Tried all permutation combination of putting the condition within {{ }} or quoting the operator or the constant value *5* the error remains same. I am new to laravel and this might be a fundamental mistake in regards to laravel or php.

Comment: `{{ }}` is for diplaying data (its an echo) .. everything inside blade directives is regular PHP ... so everything inside `@if (...)` is just PHP and you should treat it as such ... have fun and good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to understand when you need to use curly braces.
when you display your data in blade file you need to use curly braces. like

```
Hello, {{ $name }}.
```

You may construct if statements using the @if, @elseif, @else, and @endif directives. These directives function identically to their PHP counterparts:

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Your Solution

```
 @if(count($users) <= 5) <!-- if total number of rows in users table is less than or equal to 5 -->
     <h3> total number of rows less than or equal to 5 </h3> 
  @endif
```

for details go into laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `{{` and `}}`, they're not needed besides a Blade directive (`@if`in this case)

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the **{{  }}** inside the if condition.

Like this.

```
  @if(count($users) <= 5) <!-- if total number of rows in users table is less than or equal to 5 -->
     <h3> total number of rows less than or equal to 5 </h3> 
  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller change your code like this -

```
$users = User::all();
return view('front', compact('users'));
```

Blade file code-

```
@if(count($users) <= 5) <!-- if total number of rows in users table is less than or equal to 5 --><h3> total number of rows less than or equal to 5 </h3>@endif
```